# Errors in STL files when compiling CGAL C++ project in VS 2013

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, stl, cgal

For my master's thesis I'm planning to expand on the code written by someone who worked on the same problem a year ago. It is a VS 2013 solution that uses CGAL. However, I am unable to successfully build the previous code. When I try to, I get a huge list of errors, all situated in vs' own STL files like <algorithm> and <xmemory>. There is also a few IntelliSense errors in a few CGAL headers. Since the error obviously can't lie in the STL files I figure I must've botched my CGAL build somehow, but I have no clue what went wrong. Does anyone have any idea how these errors could be caused?

There are 3641 errors in total, (but most of them are in STL files and thus not interesting). Here are some of them:

```
Error   3517    error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    462
Error   3518    error C2374: 'std::pair' : redefinition; multiple initialization    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    462
Error   3519    error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    462
Error   3520    error C2059: syntax error : '<' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    462
Error   3521    error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    479
Error   3522    error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?) c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    479
Error   3523    error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    496
Error   3524    error C2433: 'pair' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    496
Error   3525    error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    496
3556    IntelliSense: identifier "DBL_MAX_EXP" is undefined c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigFloatRep.h 189
3552    IntelliSense: identifier "mpz_srcptr" is undefined  c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigInt.h  142
3553    IntelliSense: identifier "mpz_srcptr" is undefined  c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigInt.h  259
3554    IntelliSense: identifier "mpz_ptr" is undefined c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigInt.h  263
3555    IntelliSense: identifier "gmp_randstate_t" is undefined c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigInt.h  549
3585    IntelliSense: identifier "mpq_init" is undefined    c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigRat.h  45
3586    IntelliSense: identifier "mpq_init" is undefined    c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigRat.h  49
3587    IntelliSense: identifier "mpq_set" is undefined c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigRat.h  50
3588    IntelliSense: identifier "mpq_init" is undefined    c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigRat.h  53
3589    IntelliSense: identifier "mpq_set_si" is undefined  c:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL\CORE\BigRat.h  54
```

Here is the build output for my build of CGAL:

```
== Setting paths ==
Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.9
Packagenames: CGAL-4.9
== Setting paths (DONE) ==

== Generate version files ==
CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=4
CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=9
CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=0
CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=12
CGAL_SOVERSION     =12.0.0
CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
Building shared libraries
Visual Leak Detector (VLD) is not found.
Targetting Visual Studio 12 2013
Target build enviroment supports auto-linking
Using VC12 compiler.
Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)
USING CMake version: 3.7.0
System: Windows
== Generate version files (DONE) ==

== Set up flags ==
Build type: Release
USING CXXFLAGS = '/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /fp:strict /fp:except- /wd4503 /bigobj /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG'
USING LDFLAGS = '/machine:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO'
== Set up flags (DONE) ==

== Detect external libraries ==
External libraries supported:    GMP;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;    Coin3D;NTL;IPE
Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
GMP has been preconfigured:
UseGMP-file:      
  GMP include:      C:/dev/CGAL-4.9/auxiliary/gmp/include
  GMP libraries:    C:/dev/CGAL-4.9/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.lib
  GMP definitions:  
USING GMP_VERSION = '5.0.1'
Preconfiguring library: MPFR ...
MPFR has been preconfigured:
  UseMPFR-file:      
  MPFR include:      C:/dev/CGAL-4.9/auxiliary/gmp/include
  MPFR libraries:    C:/dev/CGAL-4.9/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.lib
  MPFR definitions:  
USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.0.0'
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:983 ]    _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.69.1;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.1;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.1;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.1;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.1;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.1;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.1;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.1;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.1;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.1;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.1;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.1;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.1;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.1;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.1;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.1;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.1;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.1;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.1;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.1;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.1;1.48.0;1.48;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:985 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:987 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = OFF
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:989 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:991 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 1.69.1;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.1;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.1;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.1;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.1;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.1;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.1;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.1;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.1;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.1;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.1;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.1;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.1;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.1;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.1;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.1;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.1;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.1;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.1;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.1;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.1;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.1;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.1;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.1;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.1;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.1;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.1;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.1;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.1;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.1;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.1;1.37.0;1.37
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:993 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1061 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1063 ]   BOOST_ROOT = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1065 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1067 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1069 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.69.1;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.1;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.1;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.1;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.1;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.1;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.1;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.1;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.1;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.1;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.1;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.1;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.1;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.1;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.1;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.1;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.1;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.1;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.1;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.1;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.1;1.48.0;1.48;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1162 ] location of version.hpp: C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/boost/version.hpp
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1186 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.63.0
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1272 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -vc120
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1282 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1326 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1328 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1384 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:28 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:673 (include)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:28 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:673 (include)


[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1523 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-vc120-mt-1_63;boost_thread-vc120-mt;boost_thread-mt-1_63;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:362 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0 _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1565 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_63;boost_thread-vc120-mt-gd;boost_thread-mt-gd-1_63;boost_thread-mt-gd;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:362 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0 _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1523 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-vc120-mt-1_63;boost_system-vc120-mt;boost_system-mt-1_63;boost_system-mt;boost_system
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:362 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0 _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1565 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_63;boost_system-vc120-mt-gd;boost_system-mt-gd-1_63;boost_system-mt-gd;boost_system-mt;boost_system
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:362 ]  Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0 _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0;NO_DEFAULT_PATH;NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1635 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
Boost version: 1.63.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
  thread
  system
Boost include:     C:/boost/boost_1_63_0
Boost libraries:   optimized;C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0/boost_thread-vc120-mt-1_63.lib;debug;C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0/boost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_63.lib;optimized;C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0/boost_system-vc120-mt-1_63.lib;debug;C:/boost/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-12.0/boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_63.lib
Boost definitions: 
USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.63.0'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==

== Write compiler_config.h ==
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_DENORMALS_COMPILE_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_FPU_ROUNDING_MODE_UNWINDING_VC_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_IEEE_754_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_ISTREAM_INT_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_5 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_6 - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_7 - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_MATCHING_BUG_8 - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NESTED_CLASS_FRIEND_DECLARATION_BUG - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_LIMITS - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_NEXTAFTER - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_STL - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NUMERIC_LIMITS_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_OUTOFLINE_MEMBER_DEFINITION_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TEMPLATE_IN_DEFAULT_PARAMETER_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_TYPENAME_BEFORE_DEFAULT_ARGUMENT_BUG - Success
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_USING_BASE_MEMBER_BUG_2 - Success
== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==

== Generating build files ==
Configuring libCGAL
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Core' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Core
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Core is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_ImageIO' detected
Configuring libCGAL_ImageIO
USING ZLIB_VERSION = '1.2.8'
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_ImageIO is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt5' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Qt5
libCGAL_Qt5 is missing the dependencies: Qt5OpenGL Qt5Svg Qt5 cannot be configured.
Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt5' detected
== Generating build files (DONE) ==

Configuring done
Generating done
```

Comment: The redefinitions smell like CGAL is trying to use one set on STL libs and your project is trying to use different ones.

Comment: When you build; in your "Output" window, can you change the "Show output from" combo to: "Build Order" then post the *first* error that you receive, along with the line of code that the error is complaining about.

Comment: So the first comment is 
    `1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\cstdlib(18): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'using'.`

and the line that it is about is:
    `using _CSTD size_t; using _CSTD div_t; using _CSTD ldiv_t;`